# Replacement for Future.transform?

Tags: dart

I'm going over some [older Dart code](https://github.com/dartist/redis_client/blob/master/lib/src/RedisClient.dart), addressing breaking changes with the latest Dart SDK. This one I can't figure out:

```
Future<DateTime> get lastsave => 
client.lastsave.transform((int unixTs) => 
  new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(unixTs * 1000, isUtc:true));
```

=>

```
The method 'transform' is not defined for the class 'Future<List<int>>'
```

From what I understand, the purpose of Future.transform() was to apply a synchronous transformation (see e.g. [this](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/JTm0__ff6aU/czUo1o6mWfYJ) discussion thread). I.e. convert the async call to a sync call and return the value.

Has Future.transform been replaced with something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must have been quite a while since that code was updated ;)

Just replace transform with then and it should work.

From https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/Boch2XH9Tmk

> We have also improved the Future class, and made it simpler to use. One simple “then” methods lets you apply asynchronous or synchronous functions to the result of a future, merging the three methods “chain”, “transform” and “then”. Streams and Futures should make asynchronous Dart programs easier to write and read, and should reduce some types of programming errors.

Comment: yeah, several months old. Thanks!